# Making calculator in Pascal with procedures

Tags: delphi, calculator, pascal, procedures

As title says, I've just learned something called procedures in Pascal, but i bumped in one problem. So, calculator is simple and it has only 4 operations (still learning procedures). The problem is when you type in operation (+, -, * or /) it just exits the program.

Anyway, thanks in advance!

Here's the code (I wrote it in Delphi):

```
program Calculator;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  n1, n2, s, m, multi, d: real;
  op: char;

procedure Sum(n1, n2: real; var s: real);
begin
  s := n1 + n2; // sum of 1st and 2nd number
end;

procedure Minus(n1, n2: real; var m: real);
begin
  m := n1 - n2 // 1st number minus 2nd number
end;

procedure Multip(n1, n2: real; var multi: real);
begin
  multi := n1 * n2; // multiplication
end;

procedure Division(n1, n2: real; var d: real);
begin
  d := n1 / n2; // division
end;

begin
  write('Insert first number: ');
  readln(n1);
  write('Insert 2nd number: ');
  read(n2);
  write('Insert operation: ');
  readln(op);
  if op = '+' then
  begin
    Sum(n1, n2, s);
    writeln('Result is: ', s);
  end
  else if op = '-' then
  begin
    Minus(n1, n2, m);
    writeln('Result is: ', m);
  end
  else if op = '*' then
  begin
    Multip(n1, n2, multi);
    writeln('Result is: ', multi);
  end
  else if op = '/' then
  begin
    Division(n1, n2, d);
    writeln('Result is: ', d);
  end;
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: If you're using Delphi, you can use the debugger to figure this out yourself. Click on the first `write` statement and hit F5 to set a breakpoint (a red dot will appear to the left of the line in the IDE), and then press F9. When the debugger stops at the breakpoint, hit F8 to run to the next line, or F7 to step into a procedure call. You can go step by step through your code to figure out where the problem is located and then figure out what's causing it. (Formatting your code properly will help you read it better, too.)

Comment: I formatted your code for you to make it more readable. I would also suggest that all your functions with var parameters are converted into functions that return their result. That makes them composable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call the `ReadLn()` procedure for variable n2.

By just calling `Read()` your program will get CR for the operator character and also the ending `ReadLn()` will take the last buffered CR and end the program.

When you are having trouble with your code, use the debugging possibilities to single step the program to find out what is happening.

Use Ken's advice in his comment or look into the documentation.

Comment: You threw away a teaching opportunity. :-( Not downvoting, just saying.

Comment: Oh, so that was the problem, didn't know it would cause this. Thank you!